# Swift - Variable is updated as part of in an if statement, but it's then reverting afterwards

Tags: swift

I'm building a browser that then goes off and gets some data from a variety of APIs for the URL entered. I've got the basic controls all up and running, but I'm a stumped on some code that's intended to append a 'HTTP://' to the start of the URL if the user doesn't enter it.

```
func loadAddressURL(URLpath: String) {


    //add 'http' if not entered.

    var first4 = Range(start: URLpath.startIndex,
        end: advance(URLpath.startIndex, 4))

   var URL = URLpath
    println(URL)

        if URLpath.substringWithRange(first4) != "http" {
        var URL = "http://" + URLpath
        println(URL)

    }

    println(URL)

    let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webview.loadRequest(request)
}
```

On the first print, the URL is coming in as the user entered it. The second print statement in the If statement is displaying the value with the added 'HTTP://' as expected, however after the if statement finishes the URL Var goes back to the original string the user entered, and I'm buggered if I can figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with variable scopes. If you look at your code, you define a variable URL at the top level inside the function. Then you compare the prefix and append http, but then you define a new variable inside the if statement (which is scoped now). So, the URL variable outside if is different than the variable inside if, so your changes to URL is not seen outside the if statement.

Simple make the following changes, and it should be fine,

```
func loadAddressURL(URLpath: String) {


    //add 'http' if not entered.

    var first4 = Range(start: URLpath.startIndex,
        end: advance(URLpath.startIndex, 4))

    var URL = URLpath
    println(URL)

    if URLpath.substringWithRange(first4) != "http" {
      URL = "http://" + URLpath
      println(URL)
    }

    println(URL)

    let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webview.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not the same var

```
var URL = "http://" + URLpath
```

creates a new var. use instead

```
URL = "http://" + URLpath
```